# Advanced Excel Sumif (may require VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a list of grocery orders where I am trying to sum up the total avocado purchases only for grocery orders where limes are also purchased. I know this is possible with pivot tables and helper columns, but is there a clean, repeatable formula or VBA to solve this problem?

The spreadsheet below shows an example of what I am trying to do, and I want the green cells summed up ideally without creating a helper column as I need to repeat the process many times.

[image: Grocery List Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=SUMPRODUCT(E5:E15*((B5:B15)="Avocado")*(ISNUMBER(MATCH((A5:A15)&"Lime",(A5:A15)&(B5:B15),0))))`

Sums the range with totals and multplies by two Booleans (True=1,False=0). First is if the row is Avocado and the other is if the `Bill #` concatenated with `Limes` can be found using `MATCH()`.

If both of these equate to true then you get `VALUE * 1 * 1` to sum which is the result you want.

If either is false you instead get `VALUE * 0 * 1` which will give 0 for either result.

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the solution. That is the trickiest part of my project, and I wasn't thinking of using sumproduct. Cheers!